# Enabling web vitals measurement tools in restricted staging environments

Tags: performance, web, measure, web-vitals

I want to able to use https://web.dev/measure/ on our staging environments but unfortunately, our staging environments are heavily restricted only allowing certain IPs to access it.

My Question is. Is it possible to whitelist https://web.dev/measure/ soo that I can run these tests on our stating environments?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [web.dev/measure](https://web.dev/measure/) tool uses the PageSpeed Insights API under the hood, so you could look at your server logs for the API accessing it, and see if they're consistent from run to run. If they are, the you could whitelist that IP.

Honestly, though, I'd recommend looking into [Lighthouse CI](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci), as it's designed for your use case. The [web.dev/measure](https://web.dev/measure/) tool is designed for learning.